# Rails app send multiple email to same address on getting stuck posting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, sendgrid

I am newbie and following tutorials i pust my up application and currently hosting on free heroku dyno. The issue is that some time the form is not getting posted and I got into habit of stopping it using the browser stop button and then posting it again. I have now realized that my email reputation has dropped to 40% , the reason being the same email sent to same address multiple times once i resent the form once it failed or i stopped start and resubmit form. To send email after save i am using the following code in the create action. What I should do to make sure only one email get sent.

```
  def create
@job_post = JobPost.new(params[:job_post])
@job_post.jobuuid = SecureRandom.hex(7)

if @job_post.save
    if user_signed_in?
      @job_post.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)     
    else
      @job_post.update_attribute(:user_id, 1) 
    end
  # Handle a successful save.
  # Email to JobPoster
  JobMailer.jobposting_acknowledgment(@job_post).deliver
  # Email to Admin
  JobMailer.jobposting_adminnotification(@job_post).deliver
  flash[:notice] = "Job posting is received and is being manually reviewed."
  redirect_to root_path
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

Comment: While this question addresses one part of the issue: preventing multiple sends, you can do further work to prevent test emails from getting sent by using a service like [MailTrap](http://mailtrap.io/), (just plug in its SMTP server, rather than SendGrid's).

Answer (score 0):

Move `@job_post.jobuuid = SecureRandom.hex(7)` to your new action and add a hidden field in your form, so this value is submitted. You can then use it to identify that this `@job_post` has been already submitted:

```
def create
  redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Job already submitted' if JobPost.exists?(jobuuid: params[:job_post][:jobuuid])
  @job_post = JobPost.new(params[:job_post])
  @job_post.user_id = user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : 1
  begin
    @job_post.transaction do
      @job_post.user_id = user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : 1
      @job_post.save!
      if new_job
        JobMailer.jobposting_adminnotification(@job_post).deliver
        JobMailer.jobposting_acknowledgment(@job_post).deliver
      end
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Job posting is received and is being manually reviewed."
    redirect_to root_path
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render 'new'
  end        
end
```

Note that you need to ensure that jobuuid is unique and that there is no JobPost with that number in your db. There are 268 millions of 7-digit long hex string, so if you expect extremely heavy traffic there is a potential chance for a conflict (quite small, but still there is).

Comment: After substituting new_job with @job_post.new_record? and putting @job_post.jobuuid = SecureRandom.hex(7) . It does the same work that was done by previous code. The issue is that if after filling form and pressing submit followed by quick pressing of browser stop and quick repition of two actions i.e (submit stop, submit stop), the email gets sent each time as long as i keep doing it. I tried the doing the same on devise sign up form and i couldn't make it sent more than one email. I am using captcha (humanizer) on the form but if any bot could quickly do submit /stop to send massive emails

Comment: than it just defeat the purpose of using captcha. What should i do to make sure that email gets sent only once.